# Closing a BrowserWindow loaded in a Controller

Tags: angularjs, electron

Given an app, I have a help button that in the controller class opens another BrowserWindow with the help document files in it. When I close the help window first, everything is okay. When I close the original window, the help window stays open, and then when I close it it crashes since the controller itself has already been removed. I've tried various ways of using ipc messages, but one way I think I could solve it but I haven't figured out how to broadcast a 'close' messages to all open windows. Just shutting the app down using app.quit() or app.exit(status) when the original window closes doesn't seem to close the help window either. Here's a snippet

home.html

```
<button ng-click="_ctrl.showHelp()">Help</button>
```

homeController.js

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron').remote;
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

export class HomeController {
  constructor() {} //stuff

  showHelp() {
    let win = new BrowserWindow({
      title: 'Help Pages',
      nodeIntegration: false,
      show: false
    });

    win.on('closed', () => {
      win = null;
    });

    win.load(`${__dirname}/help.html`);

    win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
      win.show();
    });
  }
}
```

index.js

```
const { app, ipcMain, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote;

let mainWindow = null;

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  app.quit();
}

app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    show: false,
  });

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;

    app.quit();  //neither of these work
    app.exit(0); //neither of these work
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
  mainWindow.show();
});
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought here, maybe add some exception handling to your NodeJS application for this case. This seems to be a server side issue and not related to angular in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you only need to have the instance of the help window on index.js, with the help window instance you can set the main window on close event to close the help window when its closed.

**Example**

```
const mainWindow = null;
const helpWindow = null;

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow()
mainWindow.on('close', function(){
   helpWindow = null
   mainWindow = null
})
```

For better pratice you would want to store all the windows on an array, but for the sake of simplicity I made this way. I hope I've helped you. Oh, use only remote and ipcRenderers on renderers, ipcMain goes only to index.js.